# Can Orbeon controls have multiple values?

Tags: orbeon

I think the answer is no, but the question has been put to me so I'd like to confirm. My understanding is that any custom XBL control that I create for use in Form Builder can have one and only one value. Is this correct?

I have always assumed this because the control name is then used in the data instance as the name of the node which contains the the value.

This question comes from the desire to have reusable components with multiple values, for example, an Address control so that addresses can be recorded consistently and the same set of fields does not need to be added many times. Orbeon does have some support for this in the form of Section Templates but because the control names stay the same in each instance of a Section Template this does not work well with our design.

The best idea I've had is that a custom control which records multiple values could encode all the values into a single text string for example in JSON. Of course, this is not ideal.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for controls to have multiple values. When that happens the values are typically stored in nested elements. I.e. a control could bound to an element `<address>`, and could create nested elements `<street>`, `<city>`,`<country>`, etc to store the different parts of the address.

In practice, you can look at how this is done in the *Image Annotation* annotation control (see [`wpaint.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/wpaint.xbl)), which creates nested elements `<image>` and `<annotation>`, leveraging the `xxbl:mirror="true"` functionality.

Comment: When you say "typically", what are the other cases? Other than nested elements, attributes can be used (and are used with an _Image Annotation_). Or alternatively any complex data structure such as JSON could be stored (we're actually using GeoJSON that for a map control).

Comment: The only trouble with the nested elements is that they are not included in the XML schema and we are relying on that to parse individual field values from the data. I was a bit surprised by this since the nested elements do appear in the `xf:instance` in the form definition.

Comment: @awilkinson Correct: attributes can be used, and you could insert JSON. There is something "impure" about putting JSON inside XML, but it is sometimes the best solution.

Comment: @awilkinson About the generated schema not taking into account those nested elements, you're right; I hadn't thought about it. I'm thinking that best way would be for the XBL component to have a way to declare what the content of the element is (using XML Schema, inside some metadata), and the schema generator should use that information. What do you think?

Comment: Right. The XBL component needs to define the structure of the content somehow in order for the the schema to be generated accurately. It may as well be defined as XML schema. That way the component is responsible for making sure the schema is accurate for its data. I think that would work well.

Comment: Sounds good; so I've created this issue, but unless it gets sponsored, it is unclear when we'll get to it. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2403

Comment: Thanks. Point taken. I'll inquire about that.